# how to connect hdfs in airflow?

Tags: airflow, hdfs, directed-acyclic-graphs, webhdfs

How to perform HDFS operation in Airflow?

make sure you install following python package

> pip install apache-airflow-providers-apache-hdfs

```
#Code Snippet

#Import packages 
from airflow import settings
from airflow.models import Connection
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from datetime import timedelta
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
 
#Define new DAG
dag_execute_hdfs_commands = DAG(
      dag_id ='connect_hdfs',
      schedule_interval='@once',
      start_date=days_ago(1),
      dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=60),
      description='excuting hdfs commands',
     )

#Establish connection to HDFS
conn =Connection(
     conn_id = 'webhdfs_default1',
     conn_type='HDFS',
     host='localhost',
     login='usr_id',
     password='password',
     port='9000',
    )
session = settings.Session()

#Following line will add new connection to you airflow default DB
#Make sure once the DAG runs successfully you comment out following line.
#Because we do not want to add same connection "webhdfs_default1" every time we perform hdfs operations.
session.add(conn) #On your next run comment this out
session.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    dag_execute_hdfs_commands.cli()
```

Once above DAG runs successfully you can perform hdfs operation hereafter
For example if you wish to list files in hdfs directory try the following code

```
#File listing operation
start_task = BashOperator(
         task_id="start_task",
         bash_command="hdfs dfs -ls /",
         dag=dag_execute_hdfs_commands
         )

start_task
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the connection `webhdfs_default` with `BashOperator`, where it works with `WebHDFSHook` hook, which create a client to query the web HDFS server. Currently there is two implemented method:

- check_for_path: to check if a file exists in hdfs
- load_file: to upload a file to hdfs

You can access the client to do other operation:

```py
webHDFS_hook = WebHDFSHook(webhdfs_conn_id="<you conn id>")
client = webHDFS_hook.get_conn()
client.<operation>
```

The client it an instance from `hdfs.InsecureClient` if the conf `core.security` is not `kerberos`, and `hdfs.ext.kerberos.KerberosClient` if it is. Here is the documentation of [hdfs cli clients](https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#module-hdfs.client), you can check what are the available operation and use them.

There is a lot of available operations like download, delete, list, read, make_dir, ..., which you can call in a new Airflow operator.